# Adobe AIR InMobi not showing interstitial /rewarded ads

Tags: actionscript-3, air, inmobi

I am trying to use InMobi to display some interstitial ads on my application, but I don't get any video. I got it working pretty well for the banner ads, but my calls for caching the interstitial doesn't seem to work. Everything seems fine in my code though...

```
InMobi.getInstance.initialize("inMobiId");
InMobi.loadInterstitial("placementId", "fullScreenAd");
```

Then, later on:

```
InMobi.showInterstitial("fullScreenAd");
```

I got these logs:

```
In load interstitial
In showInterstitial
```

Did I miss something out?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the problem "caching the calls" or "loading the videos"? Ask about fixing one thing at a time so the Answer is specific. Also show some testable code that attempts to load a video so others can test/check whats wrong. I guess they need an InMobi account to even try... Does InMobi have support forums/email for faster Answer?

Comment: Actually, the problem is the first step (caching) since no video seem to be fetched. Yes, an InMobi account is needed to the the testing. I emailed InMobi 2 weeks ago twice, but didn't get any answer.